# Generic type 'Result' specialized with too many type parameters (got 2, but expected 1)

Tags: swift, xcode10.2

[image: My code and the error]

how would I solve this error and it only appears when I import Almofire.

Comment: Please post code and error as text.

Answer (score 38):

It's `Swift.Result<T, Error>`, not `Swift.Result<T1, T2>`. If you want to pass two values, use a tuple, i.e. `Swift.Result<([Character], Data), Error>` (the tuple can be auto-expanded in a switch/case handling of the result)

Also, Alamofire defines it's own `Result<T>` type. You should prefix it with `Swift.` if you want to use the Swift 5 type.

Comment: Thank you this is my first time using Alamofire

Comment: In my case was a conflict with Alamofire, just prefixing the issue was solved. Many Thanks.

Comment: We can probably remove the first part of the answer. It is actually `Swift.Result<Success,Failure> where Failure: Error`. The real problem here is that Alamofire has it defined differently (which you mention later). The first part is confusing and incorrect

Comment: And `Success` is `T`. You're nit-picking, nothing is incorrect, and anyone who would find it confusing already knows how generics in Swift works. Besides, Alamofire replaced their internal type with the Swift 5 [around the same time this answer was written](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/commit/03433df845797f58a5cd299e741a32afc0f73408#diff-cf32291a560e3c809323292a539184fc7e688d6583f807da70e275423e5647d4)

We might as well delete the question. Yet it keep getting upvotes, so I'm guessing people still hit this problem with older versions of Alamofire.

Comment: @DanielGalasko it also begs the question, why are you here commenting on a over 2 year old answer? Surely there's better things to do on Stack Overflow, like answering questions :p

Comment: @ClausJørgensen my country is still in lockdown so I beg to differ :-D In all seriousness though I genuinely had the same error come up and forgot that Alamofire has their own result type Your answer helped me so thank you

Comment: In my case, there are three different sources for Result<>,
* Swift.Result<>
* Auth0.Result<>
* Guardian.Result<>